# How to use Kafka Connect with existing and new files (watch folder)

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

I would like to use Apache Kafka Connect to process files on a Linux server.

Use case: I have a folder with 2 million XML files in subfolders. I want to push them all to Apache Kafka in order of their timestamp. Then I want to watch the folder and subfolders for new files and also push them to Kafka in order of arrival.

Is this possible? Or do I need to split this process? Are plugins available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the spooldir connector plugin https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir

If that's not workable check out connectors.confluent.io to see other plugins from the community.

Ordering guarantees will be based on your partitioning strategy. If you need total ordering, use one partition.